# Toast Reminder on C# Windows 10 Desktop App Not Persisting?

Tags: c#, toast

I've been trying to use the 'reminder' value for the scenario attribute on a toast in a Windows 10 desktop application, and cannot get the toast to persist on the desktop.

Using the [desktop toast sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/DesktopToasts/CS) on github, I've tried to add the attribute and value to the toastXml (around line 116) with the following:

```
        IXmlNode toastBase = toastXml.SelectSingleNode("toast");
        XmlAttribute scenarioAttrib = toastXml.CreateAttribute("scenario");
        scenarioAttrib.Value = "reminder";
        toastBase.Attributes.SetNamedItem(scenarioAttrib);
```

This seems to be working as intended, as writing the toastXml out to a string gives me:

```
        <toast scenario="reminder"><visual><binding template="ToastImageAndText04"><image id="1" src="file:///X:/Users/.../Desktop/CS/bin/Debug/toastImageAndText.png"/><text id="1">Line 0</text><text id="2">Line 1</text><text id="3">Line 2</text></binding></visual></toast>
```

But, after the 7 second or so timeout, the toast on the desktop disappears and is placed in the action center.

Is there a trick I'm missing to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I know this request is ancient, but you need an "action" to make Windows treat a reminder as a reminder.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts#alarms-reminders-and-incoming-calls